# Image could not be displayed

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a profile page. I want to set a default image for those users whom have yet to upload a profile pic. However, the picture could not be displayed. It shows a cracked image. Why is that so?

Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>User Profile</title>
</head>
    <body>

<?php 

include ('connect.php');

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("Could not connect to the server");
    mysql_select_db("userprofile") or die ("Invalid database!");
    $userquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userprofile WHERE user_id = '$id'") or die ("The query could not be completed");

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($userquery)) {
            $id = $row['user_id'];
            $username = $row['user_name'];
            $firstname = $row['first_name'];
            $lastname = $row['last_name'];
            $email = $row['email'];
            $description = $row['description'];
            $image = $row['image'];

        }

if (empty($image)) {
    $image = "avatardefault.png";
}
?>
    <h2><?php echo $firstname; ?> <?php echo $lastname; ?>'s Profile</h2><br />
    <table>
        <tr><td>Username: </td><td><?php echo $username; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Firstname: </td><td><?php echo $firstname; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Lastname: </td><td><?php echo $lastname; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email: </td><td><?php echo $email; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Description: </td><td><?php  echo $description; ?></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Image: <img src = "/avatars/'.$image.'" width = "200px" height = "200px"></td></tr>
    </table>

<?php 
} else die ("You will need to specify a id!");
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I have read through some of the similar questions on stackoverflow and has also tried out the methods. Yet to no avail. Much help is needed. Thanks.

P.S I have limited knowledge on php and mysql.

Comment: **You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection.** Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.   http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started.

Comment: Will take note of that!

Comment: a while loop to fetch a single record? cargo-cult programming warning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not inside an `<?php ?>` block:

`<img src = "/avatars/'.$image.'"`

So it should be:

`<img src = "/avatars/<?php echo $image; ?>"`

Comment: Tried but it is still a cracked image.

Comment: What does `$image` contain?

Comment: $image = "avatardefault.png";

Comment: Ok. Have a look in the code of your site. How is the `<img>`-tag rendered? Are you sure the image `/avatar/avatardefault.png` exists and is accessible?

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
<img src = "/avatars/'.$image.'" width = "200px" height = "200px">
```

You've forgotten PHP tags around the .$image. part. It should read:

```
<img src = "/avatars/<?php echo $image; ?>" width = "200px" height = "200px">
```